# Is there a library that helps in creating tutorials for using my iPhone app

Tags: ios, user-experience

I created an app and got some feedback that it isn't clear what it does and how. I understand that I need to create a tutorial that is shown on initial launch.

After searching for terms like "how to create a feature tour for an iOs app", or, "Make a tutorial for an ios app" - I was getting tutorials for creating ios apps...

Simple solution would be to test for initial launch, open the tutorial slides I created, and save a flag, but maybe there is a more elegant framework that could help with features related to that (like adding popovers, callouts, screen shots etc)

Does anybody know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how complex your app is it can be easily done using an instructional overlay. An overlay would some what block the background while showing with arrows and text what the user can do in specific areas.

Comment: was hoping someone did the ground work for that

Comment: They're specific to the app so there really isn't a way to have them pre-built. There are Jquery plugins that step a user through in specific areas but they're crude and lack refinement.